# Square Loop Made of Cylindrical Wire with Uniform Cross Section

Tags: tikz-3dplot, pst-solides3d

I am trying to draw a square loop made of thick cylindrical wire with uniform cross section lying on the ground as is given in `Square_Loop.png`. Plotting such a loop in 3D as a rectangular frame drawn with lines which have no thickness seems quite straightforward in PSTricks and/or Ti*k*Z. However, increasing some dimensionality to the cross-section becomes far from easy. Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what "increasing some dimensionality to the cross-section" means? And did you manage to do the straightforward part, and if so, could you please post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-6,0) node[below right]{$y$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[left]{$z$};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
  \draw[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (2,-4);
  \draw[rounded corners] (0.2,-0.2) rectangle (1.8,-3.8);
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,transform shape] (blob) at (1,-2){};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[dashed] (blob.center) -- (5,-2,0) coordinate(B) -- (5,-2,4) node[circle,draw,inner
 sep=1.5pt,solid,label=right:$A$](A){};
 \draw[-stealth] (blob.center) -- (A);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-2,transform shape]
  \pic[draw,angle radius=2cm,"$\alpha$",angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=B--blob--A};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[semithick] (0,-4,0) -- (0,-4,1.5) (2,0,0) -- (2,0,1.5);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
  \path (-4,1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[midway,above,transform shape=false]{$b$};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (-4,1.2) -- (0,1.2);
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
  \path (2,1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[midway,above,transform shape=false]{$a$};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (2,1.2) -- (0,1.2);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the 3d effect, I failed. This is the best I could come up with in reasonable time.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,angles,quotes,calc}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,thick]
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-6,0) node[below right]{$y$};
 \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[left]{$z$};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
  \draw[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (2,-4);
  \draw[rounded corners] (0.2,-0.2) rectangle (1.8,-3.8);
  \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,transform shape] (blob) at (1,-2){};
  \begin{scope}
   \clip[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (2,-4) 
   (1.8,-3.8) -| (0.2,-0.2) -- (1.8,-0.2) -- cycle;
   \shade[top color=black!80,bottom color=black!70,middle color=gray!50,
   shading angle=-35] (0.3,0.2) rectangle (1.7,-0.3);
   \shade[top color=black!80,bottom color=black!70,middle color=gray!50,
   shading angle=-35] (0.3,-4.1) rectangle (1.7,-3.6);
   \shade[top color=black!80,bottom color=black!70,middle color=gray!50,
   shading angle=52] (-0.2,-0.3) rectangle (0.3,-3.7);
   \shade[top color=black!80,bottom color=black!70,middle color=gray!50,
   shading angle=52] (1.6,-0.3) rectangle (2.1,-3.7);
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (0.3,-0.3);
    \shade[ball color=gray!70] (0.3,-0.3) circle[radius=0.3];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (2,0) rectangle (1.7,-0.3);
    \shade[ball color=white] (1.7,-0.3) circle[radius=0.3];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,-4) rectangle (0.3,-3.7);
    \shade[ball color=gray!30] (0.3,-3.7) circle[radius=0.3];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (1.7,-4) rectangle (2,-3.7);
    \shade[ball color=white] (1.7,-3.7) circle[radius=0.3];
   \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
 \end{scope}
 \draw[dashed] (blob.center) -- (5,-2,0) coordinate(B) -- (5,-2,4) node[circle,draw,inner
 sep=1.5pt,solid,label=right:$A$](A){};
 \draw[-stealth] (blob.center) -- (A);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-2,transform shape]
  \pic[draw,angle radius=2cm,"$\alpha$",angle eccentricity=1.3] {angle=B--blob--A};
 \end{scope}
 \draw[semithick] (0,-4,0) -- (0,-4,1.5) (2,0,0) -- (2,0,1.5);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
  \path (-4,1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[midway,above,transform shape=false]{$b$};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (-4,1.2) -- (0,1.2);
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
  \path (2,1.2) -- (0,1.2) node[midway,above,transform shape=false]{$a$};
  \pgflowlevelsynccm
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (2,1.2) -- (0,1.2);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @marmot. However, as you can see the thickness of the wire of which the square loop is made is only planar (2D), not 3D. I wish I would be able to add some height/width to the thickness so that the cylindrical cross-section of the wire is visible, as is given in Square_Loop.png.

Comment: @Savchenko Sorry, I do not have `Square_Loop.png`. Is it the screen shot you post?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that one.

Comment: @Savchenko Then I do not understand what  height/width precisely means. Do you want it to have also thickness in the z-direction?

Comment: Yes. Just imagine that this is a cylindrical wire bent to form a square loop (rectangular frame). The cross-section of the wire is a full circle.

Comment: @Savchenko OK, got it. This may take a bit but I'll give it a shot in 2-3h.

Comment: Thank you so much! Take your time...